# web ui выбор технологии

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Хочу сделать (сугубо в личных целях) для приложения на Java веб интерфейс такой как, к примеру, в Transmission

[image: Transmission Web UI]
<sub>(источник: [transmissionbt.com](https://transmissionbt.com/images/screenshots/Clutch-Large.jpg))</sub>

Поскольку не особо хочется делать велосипед, нужен совет (или же вектор движения) как именно это можно сделать. Единственное что мне удалось нагуглить это древний пример на Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Минимальный набор языков для **любого** web-приложения: HTML, CSS, JavaScript.

Для того, чтобы не изобретать велосипед используйте: библиотеку JavaScript-а: [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) (+[jQuery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) для более красивых компонентов, анимации и т.д.), [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/), [Font Awesome](https://fontawesome.com/).

**Альтернативы** jQuery: AngularJS, ReactJS, VueJS (это все фреймворки JavaScript-а). Но это довольно объемные фреймворки и на их изучение уйдет немало времени (по сравнению с jQuery).

Comment: Бытует мнение, что эти _альтернативы_ - это вовсе не альтернативы, а вполне сочетаемые с jQuery фреймворки, отвечающие за совершенно другие задачи. KnockoutJS до кучи.